# Linux shell doesn't execute my c program

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

After some server update I am no able to execute an C program (it was working yesterday and something was changed in my server causing this problem).

I've at this folder /home/int/exe/ a c program named aesdecript with 777 permission. So if type the following commands as root:

```
$ cd /home/int/exe/
$ ./aesdecrypt
-bash: /home/int/exe/aesdecrypt: No such file or directory
$ sh aesdecrypt
aesdecrypt: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
$ ldconfig aesdecrypt
ldconfig: relative path `aesdecrypt' used to build cache
$ system("/home/int/exe/aesdecrypt")
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"/home/int/exe/aesdecrypt"'
```

aesdecrypt is a C program.

Someone have any idea? This program was working a couple days ago.

Below aesdecrypt source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include "aes.h"

int aes_crypt_decrypt(int encrypt, char *finput, char *foutput);

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    puts("Oi mundo!"); /* prints Magick Teste! */
    /*if( argc < 3 )
        return (1);

aes_crypt_decrypt( TRUE, argv[1], argv[2] );*/
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Regards, Tiago

Comment: Is the file executable? Try chmod a+x aesdecrypt. Also, show the output of file aesdecrypt

Comment: Would be interesting to see `ls -l aesdescript` also.

Comment: You type `aesdecript` but the shell prints out `aesdecrypt`. Something doesn't fit together here.

Comment: As a side note it bad practice to put binaries in a directory named 'src'

Comment: It is executable (777), the problem isn't the program, i've changed the code to #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include "aes.h"

int aes_crypt_decrypt(int encrypt, char *finput, char *foutput);

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
 puts("Oi mundo!"); /* prints Magick Teste! */
 /*if( argc < 3 )
  return (1);

 aes_crypt_decrypt( TRUE, argv[1], argv[2] );*/
 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Comment: @FUZxxl he said the file has 777 permission, so chmod a+x shouldn't change anything

Comment: Could you print all steps to compile and run and maybe the output of ls -l?

Comment: file aesdecrypt 
aesdecrypt: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, not stripped

Comment: What's the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: Did you try ldd yet as I suggested in my answer?

Comment: Is your system a 64-bit system? If so, it may be that your kernel doesn't have the support for 32-bit executables enabled. Try compiling it as 64-bit app in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The symptoms you are describing are very similar to those you get when trying to execute a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system and 32-bit "emulation" is not available. In that case, even if the binary is executable and everything is right, the system error code is "No such file or directory". In order to fix the problem, install support for 32-bit executables using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

This is probably what went missing after an upgrade. For a longer story, see [this article](http://www.markusbe.com/2009/09/about-running-32-bit-programs-on-64-bit-ubuntu-and-shared-libraries/).

Comment: I've just installed the ia32-libs, but I got the same problem, but I guess you are right about the cause of my problem.

Comment: @user1966670: That's the only possible cause for that weird behavior that I ever came across. Aside of that, why do you even compile that binary for a 32-bit system? Why not compile it into a native 64-bit ELF?

Comment: I going to compile to 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** In comments, the OP has shown us the output of `file aesdescrypt`, which is inconsistent with the assumptions I've made in this answer. I'll probably delete this answer once the problem is resolved, if not sooner.

If `aesdecrypt` is the name of your C *source* program, you can't execute it directly.

The shell is trying to execute it as a script, and since it doesn't start with a `#!` line, it assumes it's a `/bin/sh` script.

`/bin/sh` chokes on the C syntax.

You'll need to compile it first, for example:

```
mv aesdecrypt aesdecrypt.c
gcc aesdecrypt.c -o aesdecrypt
./aesdecrypt
```

Comment: Aesdecrypt isn't the source code, it was working a couple days ago, after some server update I've started to get this error.

Answer (score -1):

It is very likely that you're missing one or more libraries which your aesdecript program is linked to. Check with the ldd utility which library/libraries it concerns.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. It doesn't says library X not found anywhere.

Comment: @FUZxxl it won't say that when libs are missing.